# Upload Showing Blank

Tags: upload, asp-classic

There is a client of mine who recently moved his site from another server to mine. His Upload script stopped working after he moved.
I am not very good at ASP so i am in need of some help to assist him.

View code [here](http://www.codeupload.com/4177).

I tried both with

```
Count = Upload.Save("/Pictures/my/"
```

and

```
Count = Upload.SaveVirtual("/Pictures/my/")
```

> **SOLUTION as per @Tumay's comment:**
>   "it was a permission issue, its fixed now" (sic)

Comment: @Curt please don't add irrelevant tags. This question got nothing to do with classic ASP.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Sorry, the code in the link looks like classic asp to me. Theres `include` references to classic asp files too. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @Curt sorry, I just read the question, he clearly said ASP.NET so it confused me. Code is hard proof, I've edited the question and tags now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Count = Upload.Save("~/Pictures/my/"
```

Comment: it was a permission issue, its fixed now

Comment: The `~` is only for ASP.NET turns out this case is classic ASP